# customize-controls.js - extend api.previewer

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I want to remove this check -> `if ( value._dirty )` from code snippet below, but as it is located in Wordpress core file(customize-controls.js line 1919)

I can't edit that, I need to accomplish that from my theme's custom js file, but I don't know how, as I guess it should be extended and enqueued correctly. code:

```
        // Initialize Previewer
    api.previewer = new api.Previewer({
        container:   '#customize-preview',
        form:        '#customize-controls',
        previewUrl:  api.settings.url.preview,
        allowedUrls: api.settings.url.allowed,
        signature:   'WP_CUSTOMIZER_SIGNATURE'
    }, {

        nonce: api.settings.nonce,

        query: function() {
            var dirtyCustomized = {};
            api.each( function ( value, key ) {
                if ( value._dirty ) {
                    dirtyCustomized[ key ] = value();
                }
            } );

            return {
                wp_customize: 'on',
                theme:      api.settings.theme.stylesheet,
                customized: JSON.stringify( dirtyCustomized ),
                nonce:      this.nonce.preview
            };
        },

        save: function() {
            var self  = this,
                query = $.extend( this.query(), {
                    action: 'customize_save',
                    nonce:  this.nonce.save
                } ),
                processing = api.state( 'processing' ),
                submitWhenDoneProcessing,
                submit;

            body.addClass( 'saving' );

            submit = function () {
                var request = $.post( api.settings.url.ajax, query );

                api.trigger( 'save', request );

                request.always( function () {
                    body.removeClass( 'saving' );
                } );

                request.done( function( response ) {
                    // Check if the user is logged out.
                    if ( '0' === response ) {
                        self.preview.iframe.hide();
                        self.login().done( function() {
                            self.save();
                            self.preview.iframe.show();
                        } );
                        return;
                    }

                    // Check for cheaters.
                    if ( '-1' === response ) {
                        self.cheatin();
                        return;
                    }

                    // Clear setting dirty states
                    api.each( function ( value ) {
                        value._dirty = false;
                    } );
                    api.trigger( 'saved' );
                } );
            };

            if ( 0 === processing() ) {
                submit();
            } else {
                submitWhenDoneProcessing = function () {
                    if ( 0 === processing() ) {
                        api.state.unbind( 'change', submitWhenDoneProcessing );
                        submit();
                    }
                };
                api.state.bind( 'change', submitWhenDoneProcessing );
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove that?

Comment: if you are familiar with wordpress theme customizer you should know that in the last update version 4.1 only the control values are saving which were changed. in short I want it for theme activation(first time) to save all customizer control values in database :)

Comment: I'm familiar with theme customizer API and I think you are trying to do things in the wrong way. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, I think you are wrong in the concept. You want to save theme options after first activation. Activate a theme doesn't mean that the user will use the theme customizer, so I think there is nothing to do with the customizer javascript because it will be loaded only if the user go to the customizer screen and because is a client-side code. There are better ways.

My suggestion is to use `after_switch_theme` and `switch_theme` actions hooks:

- `after_switch_theme` to save theme options after the theme is activated.
- `switch_theme` to remove theme options if the theme is deactivated (optional)

Example:

```
add_action("after_switch_theme", "cyb_save_theme_options_on_activation");
function cyb_save_theme_options_on_activation() {
    set_theme_mod('background-color', '#FFF');
}
```

I think it would be good to check if the option being added/update has a user custom value; if so I think it shouldn't be changed. For example:

```
add_action("after_switch_theme", "cyb_save_theme_options_on_activation");
function cyb_save_theme_options_on_activation() {
    if( get_theme_mod('background-color') == '' ) {
        set_theme_mod('background-color', '#FFF');
    }
}
```

If you are using theme options instead of theme mods:

```
add_action("after_switch_theme", "cyb_save_theme_options_on_activation");
function cyb_save_theme_options_on_activation() {
    //add_option adds the option if it doesn't exist in the database
    //Use update_option if you want to override existing option in the database or add it if doesn't exist
    add_option('background-color', '#FFF');
}
```

I'm still think that you are wrong in the approach. From your comment, you want to save all options into database, even options with default values, when the use click on "Save and Publish" and not on theme activation. To do that, you could use `customize_save_after` action hook:

```
add_action( 'customize_save_after', 'customize_save_after' );
function customize_save_after( $wp_customize ) {
    //Save the theme options here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for good answer, but tha is NOT my solution. All theme options(2000+) are located in the Theme Customizer and without saving them in database theme would not be activated... Thats why I need to extend `api.previewer` to remove that check, after that all Theme Customizer Control values will be saved in the database, when user clicks Save & Publish... That's my huge problem. In 4.0 that was happening by default.

Comment: No matter how many options you have, I don't see the problem. Again, **activating a theme doesn't mean that the user will use the customizer**, so your approach is incorrect. Anyway, see my edited answer; I've included a function triggered after the user click on "Save and publish" button in the customizer screen where you can save all the theme options.

Comment: And please, think what you want before you ask. You said: "I want it for theme activation (first time) to save all customizer control values in database" so I though you want to save customizer options in theme activation. Now you say that you want to save them "when user clicks Save & Publish".

Comment: I said "when user clicks Save & Publish" for you to understand better and YES it means that user will use theme csutomizer because theme depends on theme cusotmizer and without saving those (2000+) options theme won't work? It's so easy mate sorry but why you cant understand??

Comment: for example this code snippet is from my index page `<?php if ( $sidebar['general_position'] === 'top' ) : ?>` here `$sidebar['general_position']` is a Customizer option...

Comment: You confirm my thought: you are confused. You are the one that don't understand that activating a theme doesn't mean that the user will go to the customizer screen. You are the one that don't understand that performing tasks on theme activation should be done usgin `after_switch_theme` action hook. You are the one that don't understand that using client-side code (javascript) can not ensure that server-side task (PHP code in this case) will be executed. If you want to stick with "I want to this in this way", go ahead, but I can not help you.

Comment: just a note that with the modern customizer the line between active and inactive themes are even more blurred than before. A theme might be customized before it is getting active. not sure if theere is a filter fired before that but maybe the old fashion way of checking if the settings are in the DB and if not than populate them, is the most robust one.